# Setting the ring stream volume on android 2.3 doesn't actually change the volume

Tags: android

I'm using seekbars to adjust the ringtone volume, but it doesn't seem to work on gingerbread. It works fine on 4.1.

```
ringerVlmSeekBar
         .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }
   //When progress level of seekbar2 is changed
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0,
        int progress, boolean arg2) {
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(
        AudioManager.STREAM_RING, progress, 0);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since I didn't get any answers or comments, here's the reason that I discovered: different versions of android have different ways of linking the audio streams, which means that on my android 2.3 device, you can't change the notification volume and ringer volume independently. Hopefully this will help anyone who has this same issue.